# Can’t SSH from my laptop using a terminal to an VM server (RedHat 7) which is installed in my laptop

Tags: linux, vmware

I have followed the standard approach which [I found in this Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/422407/how-do-i-set-up-an-ip-address-on-a-linux-vm-running-in-vm-player-so-i-can-access). I have pasted the link below from were I got the step.

I have edited the VM's network adapter to "Host-only: a private network" but still I’m facing issue connecting with SSH.

I have not been able to restart the network using `systemctl restart network` and I’mm getting an error:

```
job for network.service failed. see systemctl status network.service and journalctl -xn for details
```

So I did that. When I checked the status with `systemctl status network.service` I got another error.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking and what problem you're running into.  Your "question" refers to "this answer" and "original poster" and such, so it seems like you just copied and pasted somebody's instructions from somewhere else. (Where?) Exactly what are you *trying* to do?  If it's just to use SecureCRT to ssh to a RHEL VM, it should just involve ensuring that sshd is enabled in the VM.  Is the use of host-only networking relevant?

Comment: sorry for the complicated question. i m trying to do a ssh from my laptop (host) to vm server which i have in installed my system. the steps which i have pasted are the steps which i got online.i tried it, it didnt work for me.

Comment: You haven't answered my other questions: Is host-only networking a requirement?  If not, then you're making your situation unnecessarily complicated.  Is sshd enabled in the RHEL guest?  Where did you get those steps from?  You should rewrite your question so that it's clear what you're asking.  And for clarity, it'd probably better to remove all of the steps you copied and pasted and instead just provide a link to them.

Comment: i have edited the network adapter in vm to "Host-only: a private network"